# How to create a CMS User account for mailprocess

Tags: user-account

Sorry for the Newbie question, but often the extensive civicrm documentation assumes user knowledge that newbies don't have.

I cannot find out how to create a CMS user.

I am trying to setup email on my drupal 9 CIVIcrm using https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/, which specifies the need for a "user login account ( -u mailprocess )" with "these minimum permissions." "These minimum permissions" is a hyperlink to: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/. Under the section "Choosing a CMS user" it specifies that it has to have correct permissions. At minimum those are:

- View all contacts
- Access CiviCRM
- Access CiviMail

OK, so I have deduced from this that the term "user login account" is synonymous with "CMS user," but nowhere can I figure out how to add either one. I cannot even figure out whether that is a CIVIcrm "CMS user" or a drupal "CMS user." The best I can do is to add a "contact" but that requires an email address, which makes no sense for a systems user, such as "mailprocess."

I also saw the possibility of adding a "role", aka "user" in some computer languages. But the roles do not allow setting these three permissions.

So, can someone explain how to create the "mailprocess" user and set the above permissions.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1):

You're right the docs intentionally don't repeat information that really belongs in other software's documentation. But it does assume you know CMS means, in this case, Drupal. Drupal is separate software that has its own documentation. For managing user accounts in drupal, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/user-chapter.html

Comment: Thank you. Your answer also address a lingering doubt that I had on whether CIVIcrm inherits the users of the host CMS. It makes sense that it does, but I have learned in life to be careful about my assumptions. I am an economist and there are lots of jokes about our fallacious assumptions!

Comment: This answer leaves out an obvious problem. Adding a drupal user requires an email. The system user does not have an email, so I put my own email address in. That was rejected because it is already used in my own user account. It is inconvenient to create a new email account for every system account. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you just use a fake email?

Comment: I didn't try. Instead I used a rarely used email account.

Comment: If your mail system lets you use "plussed addresses" you can use that to avoid needing a separate address.  So if your address is joe@example.org, use joe+cron@example.org, joe+drupal@example.org etc. Drupal sees it as different but the mails end up in the same mailbox. Google lets you use those.